# How to get data from the server back into the server on the next request.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http

Writing a Node/Express app. When a user requests a page, I send it with my mongo document data, however if they say go to an edit page, when I receive the next request I lose all of that precious mongo data and only get whats in the edit form, so I lose a lot of information regarding the thing they are editing. Is there a way that I can send the entire document back along with the body of the request that contains the initial mongo data?

Comment: You need to store the data in cookies. We call these `session`. Look them up. [Here is a good library run by Mozilla for Ref](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions)

Comment: that looks great, but it may be a bit much for this question. I have an event driven application that may need reference dozens of events, we would prefer not to put that much data on the browser. All we need to do is to get the mongo document back with the next request. Sessions does look good for well, session data. Maybe we'll just to store it all in a blank input div or something?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between storing the data in the header (which would be a cookie) or in the body of a request. Both are being transported on the payload.

Comment: So how can I get the initial response data back in the next request, that may be a better way to put it. Or am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Are you using the core http module packed with node or are you using express or some type of framework?

Comment: express is what I am using. Im sure I could pull in http though would that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131860/discussion-between-magreenberg-and-illcrx).